# Download multiple files in Python loop, only first works

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to download few videos from list of links.
Every line in text file is one link.
When I try to download all videos in loop, only first one is working.
Videos are from 60 - 100 MB.
Loop continues afterwards, but files are empty.

Thank you for help.

```
 def download():
     name = 'video'
     a = 1
     with open('download.txt') as f:
         lines = f.readlines()
         for line in lines:
              url = line
              response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
              name = name + str(a)
              filename = name + '.mp4'
              with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                  f.write(response.content)
              a = a + 1
```

Comment: Where are you first declaring "name"? It appears as appending to itself in the loop but I don't see where it's initialized. Perhaps the name is just growing and not being reset.

Comment: Sorry I added it. It was in my code, so this isnt problem. Loop creates files with unique name, but they are just empty except first.

Comment: Can you also post a snip of the contents in the file?

Comment: Are those links really having content?

Comment: There is 400 Bad Request error in every file.
Links are ok when I open them. Tried to time.sleep but didnt help.

Comment: If you change the order of the urls in `download.txt`, does that change which downloads are successful?  Is it always the first url that succeeds, no matter which one is first?

Comment: Only first file is everytime succesful, even with different order in list.

Comment: The lines you get from `.readlines()` include the newline character at the end, and you aren't calling `.strip()` or otherwise getting rid of it.  So I'd expect ALL of the downloads to fail, except possibly the last one (if the file didn't end with a newline).

Comment: jasonharper: oh thank you, it is working now. I havent thought about it

Comment: If an answer solves your problem, mark it as the solution using the checkmark, don't use tags in your title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def download():
    name = 'video'
    a = 1
    with open('download.txt') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(line.strip(), name + str(a) + ".mpg")
            a += 1
```

This code worked for me.

Depending on your purpose, you may want to account for security, robustness (what happens if one download fails?), performance (concurrency?).

Comment: Thank you. Is it just for personal and teaching purpose now, but I will try to improve it. Sollution from jasonharper worked too, it was just error with formation of lines in download.txt.